# Use git commands with Google Cloud Builder

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to use Google `Cloud Build` with GitHub to make a CI/CD pipeline.
However I'm struggling with GCB...

Below, a very simple pipeline :

1. run `npm install` --> it works
2. run `npm test`--> it works
3. run `npm run css:ALL`(`rm` some files + do some minifying stuff) --> seems to work
4. run some `git` commands --> **doesn't work**

Errors:

```
Step #3: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Step #3: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']
  # run test
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['test']
  # build css files
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['run', 'css:ALL']
  # git stuff
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    args: ['add', '-A']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    args: ['commit', '-m', '"some message"']
```

Do you have any clue?

My objective is simply to `git add` all build stuff and `push` them back in my `branch`.
Thanks

Comment: Does your local repo have .git folder? maybe you can try `git init`.

Comment: By committing the changes, won’t that cause another cloud build to trigger? Just wondering whether we have an infinite loop here

Answer (score 9):

Cloud Build is a great product!! With some boring things... the .git folder is not copied with the source code.

If you run your cloud build manually, simply add an empty `.gcloudignore` file at the root of your repository. Thanks to it, the `.git` directory won't be ignored and uploaded with your code.

But this trick doesn't work with trigger. For this, I use this step

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
        # Cloud Build doesn't recover the .git file. Thus checkout the repo for this
        git clone --branch $BRANCH_NAME https://github.com/path/to/yourRepo.git /tmp/repo ;
        # Copy only the .git file
        mv /tmp/repo/.git .
```

Then you can use git, with a valid and existing `.git` dir

Comment: Or you can just add `git init`

Comment: For the trigger method, does it work with the private repos?

Comment: @YeLinAung use Google source repository mirror in that case